# Javascript demo hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a blog http://justgagan.wordpress.com/, where I want to show some demo of my javascript's scripts. I know I could do this with tweaking my example for WordPress, but it will increase my pages load time, since I had to add this on body. Is there any site, which could host my example in raw form and provides Apis for embedding that example in my blog. Link would also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for http://jsfiddle.net/. You can [embed fiddles](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/embedding.html) easily.

Comment: It is what I am looking for. But, I am not able to embed this in wordpress.com.

Comment: Embedding is worpress.com issue not the jsfiddle.net. http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/html-iframe?replies=17 :(

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know that.